# Insert object/texture based on specific value or color (Photoshop, Illustrator, etc)

Tags: adobe-illustrator, adobe-photoshop

In a game engine such as Unity, a topdown map can be created by repeating a small number of tiles over and over. The layout of the tiles can be created either manually or by code.

I wonder, with the right kind of indata, is it possible to compile a similar topdown "tilemap" in a software such as Photoshop or Illustrator? Is it possible for the tiles to include graphics that extend beyond the edges of the the tiles (like sprites in a videogame)?

In this case the map is based mostly on GIS data. The GIS data will be in vector format (shp, dwg) and/or raster format (tif, png).

If the data is in raster format, each tile will be represented by a cell in the raster. If the data is in vector format, the tile could be represented by either a point or a polygon. Each cell, point or polygon will hold a value and color that represents a specific tile/texture/object.

[image: Raster and points representing a field in a forest.]
*Raster and points representing a field in a forest.*

So far, I have tried to open a raster in Photoshop and use Pattern overlay to texturize the cells in the raster. Since each value has a different color, I can select all of the cells of a certain value/color and then overlay these cells with a texture. A limitation with this approach is that the texture has to be fully contained within the cell. If I want the tile to have an element such as a tree or a house that stretches beyond the edges of the tile (overlapping neighbouring tiles) I need to find a different approach.

Perhaps there is a better way to achieve this in Illustrator?

In Illustrator, if you have a point or polygon file, is it possible to select points or polygons of a certain value/color and replace them with objects or images?

Alternatively, can you recommend another graphics editor that would be better suited for this kind of task?

I use Photoshop CS4. I currently don't own Illustrator, so the answer doesn't have to be limited to any specific version.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: This is pretty straight forward to do in a browser with html/javascript. Are you familiar with that? Sadly, an answer about web coding wouldn't be on topic here. Alternatively a script could be made for Photoshop, but for me it would be a bit more cumbersome as the api is a bit quirky.

Comment: I'm fairly new to Adobe Creative Suite, so I won't bother posting an answer, but a script, as @Wolff mentioned, would seem like the best starting point for this kind of thing, if you want to stay in the app itself.